# SharePoint 2013 DataSheet view

Tags: 2013, list-view, view, datasheet

I've issue with SharePoint DataSheet view / quick edit.

I've a library called Lib and in the library folder Folder1. In my AD I've 2 users - User1 and User2

**User1** has contribute permission to the web.

**User2** has contribute permissions only to the Folder1.

1. When I login to the site with User1 and open the folder1 I'm able to
   Switch to Quick edit and open DataSheet view
2. When I login to the site with User2 and open the folder1 the
   QuickEdit is not disabled and when I switch to datasheet view, I see
   no data (only columns) and no table control.

Is it required to have contribute permissions on the list level?

Update:
When I click to Stop editing I get JS error:

> Unable to get property 'controllerId' of undefined or null reference
>   inplview.js (1,5586)

**DataSheet View:**
[image: DataSheetView]

Comment: Any screenshots to go along with this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't mean datasheet view in the SharePoint 2010 sense correct?  That datasheet view (via ActiveX) is no longer part of 2013.

Comment: In 2013 you have also DataSheet view, but it is no more ActiveX :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same need as you and dug around a bit. It would seem that you do need at least contribute permission on the entire list to be able to "Quick edit".

IT's really a shame, it would have been perfect if it worked but only showed the items the user does in fact have contribute (Or higher) permission to.

The offical answer is here: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/240512

On a sidenote this puts me in a bit of trouble as I intended to setup a list with at custom permission allowing only creation, and the have a workflow to change permission to include edit. And once the item is marked complete it should revert to default (SO nobody can edit it). I need it this way around on order to make sure the list does not grow with items that have custom permissions...

//M